# Exporting a variable from an alias to a script in .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm trying to make a bunch of my scripts work.

The situation is this:

I am calling an alias, for example, `rxcmp`, which is supposed to create a file. For this to happen I need to do the following: get the current path, save it into a variable, move to my /.scripts directory, run said script, and pass the path in which the alias was called, so the file is created there, not in the .scripts directory. So far I have this in my .bashrc

```
alias gotoScripts='
path=$(pwd)
cd /home/alex/.scripts
'
alias rxcmp='
gotoScripts
./rxcmp.sh
'
```

And the script itself

```
echo "Component name: "
read name
nameUI=$name"UI"
nameContainer=$name"Container"
echo "Path: "
read path
cd ./$path
echo "import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import UI from $nameUI

const mapStateToProps =(state, props) => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({});

export const $nameContainer = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(UI);">$nameContainer".jsx";
```

so I am asking for the path, but it was supposed to be a relative, to the place of calling the script. Right now the files are being generated in the .scripts directory

I tried exporting like this

```
alias gotoScripts='
path=$(pwd)
cd /home/alex/.scripts
export path
'
alias rxcmp='
gotoScripts
echo $path
# ./rxcmp.sh
'
```

But nothing got echoed. How can I pass the original path to the next script?

Comment: If you have several commands to execute, use a function instead of an alias

Comment: Here is a cross site duplicate listing reasons / best practices about why chose one or the other : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Comment: Don't do `cd ./$path`, `cd "$path"` will work whether it's an absolute or relative path. I'd even remove the whole `cd` and invoke the script from the path it needs to be executed from using its absolute path (maybe using an alias). `alias rxcmp='/home/alex/.scripts/rxcmp.sh'` and run from the directory you were running your aliases from

Comment: Not using cd $path and just calling the script makes way more sense. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to quote constant strings, unless they have spaces or other characters that could be parsed as syntax. You **do** need to quote parameter expansions. That is, `echo hello` is fine as it is, but `echo $foo` is buggy unless it's replaced with `echo "$foo"` (well, even then it won't always print the exact value of the variable `foo`, but that's due to issues with `echo`, not with issues with the quoting). See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)

Comment: (...and consider the "don't use aliases at all unless you're in one of the very, very few situations where you can't use a function instead" advice reiterated; among many other pertinent differences, you can export a function with `export -f`, but you can't export an alias at all).

Comment: That said, having scripts depend on `.bashrc` contents *at all* is a very bad idea. `.bashrc` is run for **interactive** shells. Scripts are often run from *noninteractive* shells. And making a script only work for your user account means anyone else who tries to run it will find themselves very confused.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy These scripts are only for my personal machine. Is there another way to call the scripts in an alias-like way, without using .bashrc? Right now I just added aliases, and they target scripts. Example: `alias runScript="/home/alex/.scripts/runScript.sh"`. Is this ok, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @AlexIronside, aliases and functions are both invoked the same way. No matter if you define `alias gotoScripts='path=$(pwd); cd /home/alex/scripts; '` or `gotoScripts() { path=$PWD; cd /home/alex/scripts; }`, it's still started just with the command `gotoScripts`.

Comment: ...now, if you want to make the `path` variable be visible to subprocesses, then you want to `export` it. Replace the `path=$PWD` with `declare -gx "path=$PWD"` (on bash 4.0 or newer), or just add an `export path` command.

Comment: I'm not using the `$path`s anymore. Now I'm just running the scripts directly. Is this use case correct or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190930/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-alex-ironside).

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you are looking for. But you can get the previous directory from before you did a cd from the variable $OLDPWD. This still holds the path you are looking for.